# Как правильно использовать Celery и Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, celery

Есть необходимость отправлять уведомления разным пользователям, которые находятся в разных городах.

Есть несколько идей, как можно это сделать:

1. Передать город, как объект в функцию Celery.

Но я где-то слышал, что передавать объект в функцию - не правильно.

```
@shared_task
def send_to_users(city):
    users = User.objects.filter(city=city)
    for user in users:
        send_notify(user)
```

Плюс, не кажется лучшим способом итерировать по queryset'у

2. Передать city.id

Этот вариант не сильно отличается от предыдущего, разве что выборка города происходит в самой функции.

```
@shared_task
def send_to_users(city_id):
    city = City.objects.get(id=city_id)
    users = User.objects.filter(city=city)
    for user in users:
        send_notify(user)
```

3. Создавать задачу, для каждого `user`.

Этот подход кажется интересным тем, что я вижу, какому `user` не отправилось сообщение, если что-то пошло не так

```
@shared_task
def send_to_user(user):
    send_notify(user)
```

Но не кажется правильным плодить 100500 задач, для такой простой операции.

Что должны возвращать эти функции ? 
Если я передаю список юзеров, которым нужно отослать уведомления, то правильно вернуть список тех, кому отправился ?

Я так понимаю, что функции celery должны быть короткими, и не включать в себя проверки на наличие в БД, проверки состояний пр.

Но когда функция вызывается из метода модели, делать выборки из БД - значит замедлить отклик.

Как делать правильно ? Какие лучшие практики ?

Comment: «не включать в себя проверки на наличие в БД» — если я всё правильно понимаю, вы неправильно понимаете. Задачи Celery по определению являются отложенными, и между моментом создания задачи и моментом выполнения задачи объект может оказаться удалён, так что лучше наличие в БД всё-таки проверить

Comment: 1. Учититывая тот факт что все в питоне объект, мне не очень понятно зачем вообще нужны параметры в функциях...)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сказал, что конкретное решение зависит от того, как много у вас пользователей, и насколько важно доставить каждому письмо. Сначала пройдусь по идеям:

1. Как уже написали в комментариях, на момент выполнения задачи объект может быть удален. Тут скорее всего имели ввиду модель, который хранит свое состояние в БД. Объект, который свое состояние не хранит в принципе передать можно, но могут возникнуть проблемы при его десериализации. Так что с мнением, что объекты лучше не передавать в отложенные задания я полностью согласен.
2. см пункт 1
3. Я бы использовал такой подход, если бы количество пользователей было бы порядка сотен, и было бы очевидно, что завтра их не станет в 10-100 раз больше. Тут есть проблема в том, что такие задания могут долго выполнятся, так как на каждого пользователя открывается соединение, отправляется письмо, закрывается соединение, и происходить всякая машинерия celery. И если пользователей много, разница во времени между первым отправленным и последним отправленным письмом может быть велика.

Истина как всегда где то по середине. На мой взгляд хорошее решение этой задачи - это разбить письма, которые нужно отправить пользователям на чанки. Отправка по городам это тоже своего рода разбиение, но сдается мне что оно далеко не равномерное, и процентов 80 пользователей могут находится в одном городе.

Сделайте в celery две задачи:

1. `mailing_by_city(city_id)` - отправка писем пользователям конкретного города. Функция будет выбирать пользователей для города, нарезать их на куски, и передавать в функцию `send_emails`. Так же возможно, что она будет дожидаться результата отправки писем, тут лучше отправку выделить в отдельную очередь
2. `send_emails(users)` - будет отправлять письма группе пользователей, и возвращать результат отправки.

Про функции в celery - они должны быть такими, какими требуется. Если требуются какие то длительные вычисления или парсинг достаточно больших документов, то функции будут выполнятся медленно. Такие функции лучше выделять в отдельные очереди, и назначать им отдельных воркеров.

Если функция в фоновом режиме обрабатывает и анализирует запрос пользователя, и сохраняет результат этого анализа - то тут как ни крути в базу надо сходить.

Я бы сказал что функции должны выполнять одну конкретную задачу. Конкретность должна определятся здравым смыслом. Если функция будет слишком медленной, или задач будет очень много, то такие функции/задачи лучше выделять в отдельные очереди.

Вот несколько полезных ссылок:

1. [нарезка на чанки в celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chunks)
2. [массовая рассылка писем в django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#send-mass-mail). Проблема этой функции в том, что она возвращает только количество отправленных писем. Никакой дополнительной обработки. Можно по подобию сделать свою функцию отправки писем.
3. [приложение для отправки писем django-celery-email](https://github.com/pmclanahan/django-celery-email). Тут уже интереснее, в принципе реализована та концепция нарезки на чанки, которую я описал. Переотправка писем, если они упали с ошибкой происходит, но опять же никакой дополнительной обработки нет. Можно доработать код, и добавить обработчик неотправленного письма. Главное понимать, что с этим неотправленным письмом потом делать.

Comment: Тот ответ, которого я ждал!
Большое спасибо!